# Filter list by firebase conditions in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a StreamBuilder feeding data to a list which is later displayed in a stack.

I want to filter (remove) certain cards from being added to the List[] by these rules:

- I'm the owner of the card ('ownerId' == currentUserId)
- I've liked the card ('liked.' contains = currentUserId)

I choose to do a StreamBuilder because I'd like to update the stack automatically after the user interacts with it (by liking it, it disappears and shows the next). For my understanding, a stream serves that purpose. But please correct me if I'm wrong and if there's a better approach.

```
streamCard() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: postRef
            .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
            .limit(10)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return circularProgress();
          }
          List<PostCard> cards = [];
          snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
            cards.add(PostCard.fromDocument(doc));
          });
```

If "cards" isn't empty:

```
return Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: cards,
```

In Firebase, I have:
"Cards" > "cardID" > with "ownerId" and "liked" fields ("liked" contains every uid who has liked it).

The idea is to compare the current uid with the contents of each cardID. If they're present, dismiss that card and try the next.

I've been struggling with this problem for a while, I appreciate any help!

Edit Firestore structure:
[image: Firestore Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are trying to do is a logical `OR` query on your firestore, which is very limited as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations). For comparison, with you where trying to make a logical `AND` all you had to do it stack 2 `where()` calls in your query.

So you can't simply limit this in the query itself (in this case, your `stream`) but you can operate it in the stream's builder, which could be done doing something this:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return circularProgress();
    }
    List<PostCard> cards = [];
    snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
        List<String> liked = List.castFrom(doc.get("liked"));
        // currentUserId is previously populated
        if(doc.get("ownerId") == currentUserId || liked.contains(currentUserId)){
            cards.add(PostCard.fromDocument(doc));
        }
    });
    return cards;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'd actually have to use (owner != currentuid || "liked" doesn't contain) in order to add, is there a way to use doesn't contain?
I tried the code and got
`QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: []("ownerId")`

Comment: Sorry about that, the newer versions use `document.get(field)` instead of `document["field"]`, should work now, I did not understood what you meant with a way to use doesn't contain, but I guess you just have to change the if to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Fixed, thanks! But contains doesn't work `Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'contains'.`

Comment: Change it to `containsValue` instead of `contains`, should do the trick, I will edit that into the answer.

Comment: Still :/ `Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance method 'containsValue'.
Receiver: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: containsValue("SKU7rURznWUJSFDqLcykrd30Ott2")`

Comment: You first need to cast the list into a list of strings and then use `contains(value)`, check the edited answer, hopefully it will work now :)

Comment: I'm getting type `'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'` almost there xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222407/discussion-between-rafael-lemos-and-itslucca).